# Is there a way to use a method from one class (Activity) in another?

Tags: android, android-intent

As from my previous post I am working on getting some buttons to be functional. And some of these buttons call certain people. For instance - Mother

I have the actual dialing code in another file called "DialHomeDevice" -- Yes I love Stargate.

I am trying to access that method in a call intent here is what I have so far:

```
        callMomBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
            Intent dialMom = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DHD.dialMom());
            startActivity(dialMom.);
        }
    });
```

DHD has been declared at the top of the file Like so

```
    private DialHomeDevice DHD = new DialHomeDevice();
```

As well here is the code for that method of the DHD:

```
    public void dialMom() {
    prefs = getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:"
            + prefs.getLong(Constants.momNumber, 411)));
    startActivity(callIntent);
}
```

And constants is just where I store the numbers.

Now what is puzzling me is that I cant use DHD.dialMom() inside of the intent to call.
What is the best way to fix this.

Intent dialMom = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DHD.dialMom()); gives the following error:
The constructor Intent(MainActivity, void) is undefined

And startActivity(callIntent); gives me this error: 
The method startActivity(Intent) in the type Activity is not applicable for the arguments (Class)

Comment: you cannot call function through intent. intents used to ask android to launch an activity for you.

Comment: Do you mean to start the `MainActivity` when the button is pressed? Or do you mean to send the call intent to be handled by another app? You could just do something like: `public void onClick(View v) { dialMom(); }` which would then make a call intent and send it to be handled by an activity that can call.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do here. It doesn't really make sense to ask another Activity to do something without leaving the current Activity. If you are actually trying to switch to a different Activity, then you are on the right track by sending an intent. But if you just want to call a method that does something from the current activity then either that method should be moved to the the current activity or it should be placed in a third utility class rather than in one of the activities.

Comment: The question you're asking is one that Fragments are intended to answer. (See http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html .) Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

To correct the constructor error you just need to add an empty public constructor to the class.

`public DialHomeDevice(){}`

Using an intent still wouldn't be the best solution for this though. A singleton would work great here and allow you to call it at any time.

To use it you would just call `DialHomeDevice.newInstance(someObject)` or `DialHomeDevice.getInstance().desiredMethod()`. The caveat is that this will only work properly if you ensure that no more than one instance is used at a time and that threading is handled appropriately.

```
public class DialHomeDevice {
    private static DialHomeDevice ourInstance = null;
    private Activity context;
    private Object objAnything;

    public DialHomeDevice(){
        if ( ourInstance == null ) { ourInstance = this; }
    }

    public static DialHomeDevice newInstance(Object objAnything) {
        if ( ourInstance == null ) {
            ourInstance = new DialHomeDevice();
        }
        ourInstance.objAnything = objAnything;
        return ourInstance;
    }

    public static DialHomeDevice getInstance(){
        if ( ! isInstantiated() ) { ourInstance = new DialHomeDevice(); }
        return ourInstance;
    }

    static boolean isInstantiated(){
        return (ourInstance != null);
    }

    static void setObjAnything(Object objAnything){
        outInstance.objAnything = objAnything;
    }
}
```

Comment: I will check this out and get back to you later. Sorry for not accepting it but my project went from one thing to another all of a sudden.